# Convert PHP object to associative array and convert not enough

Tags: php, object, associative-array

I'm using this code for convert PHP object to associative array.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BTzvU.png)
Input:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BVI1c.png)
Then output:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vA1gE.png)
In "task.type" can't be associative array!

And I want it like this:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1CMu0.png)
Thanks for much!!

Comment: Welcome. Don't post [images of code](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-errors-when-asking-a-question)!

Comment: [Please do not upload images of code/data/errors](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551), images are hard to read and troubleshoot. Please [edit] your post and add the code here as text. Be sure to take the [tour] and read [ask].

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if you need to get associative array from your request, try it:

```
json_decode($request, true)
```

Comment: And my code: 
$post = json_decode(json_encode($this->res_body), true);